# Redirect on submit based on search query and location

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a search feature based on a text input and a drop-down.

So I am trying to make it work with the following form fields:

- Text input {text_1}
- Drop-down (2 options)
- Submit button

If first option is selected in the drop-down the form should be submitted to `https://url1/?={text_1}`, if second option is selected it should be submitted to `https://url2/?={text_1}`.

I have written so far:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text_1" name="text_1" value="test" data-alias="" class="form-control">
    <select id="selectlist_1" name="selectlist_1" data-alias="" class="form-control">
        <option value="option_1" >Option_1</option>
        <option value="option_2" >Option_2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Otherwise, there is also this example: https://hii.com/careers/

Comment: Do you want the redirection to happen already when the user *selects* a value in the drop-down, even before they click the submit button? Then why have a submit button at all?

Comment: No. I want to redirect when user click submit.

Comment: I understand. Have you written any code or tried anything to reach the goal?

Comment: yes 
<form> 
<input type="text" id="text_1" name="text_1" value="test" data-alias="" class="form-control">
<select id="selectlist_1" name="selectlist_1" data-alias="" class="form-control">
             <option value="option_1" >Option_2</option>     
             <option value="option_2" >Option_2</option>  
        </select>
<button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: Since you tagged the question with "javascript", I assume you understand scripting is required here, but your form you pasted above contains no scripting at all. Here on Stack Overflow we expect you to draft a solution before being handed a solution. In other words, we'd rather fix your solution instead of writing a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example:

```
    <script>
        function go(v){
            if (v.url.value===1){
            v.action="http://www.google.com"
          }else {
            v.action="http://www.apple.com"
          }
        }
    </script>

    <form onsubmit="go(this)">
        <input type="text" name="text_1" value="txt">
        <select name="url">
            <option value="1">Google</option>
            <option value="2">Apple</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Augment a simple form with the controls you want, with a script that sets up a behaviour where the form's `action` attribute value changes with the selection in the drop-down control:

```
<form>
    <input name="foobar" />
    <select name="fruit">
        <option value="apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    </select>
    <script>
        (script => {
            const fruit_control = script.closest("form").elements.fruit;
            fruit_control.addEventListener("change", ev => {
                ev.target.form.action = ({
                    "apples": "https://url_1",
                    "oranges": "https://url_2"
                })[ev.target.value];
            });
        })(document.currentScript);
    </script>
</form>
```

The value of the text input control will be sent with the query string, i.e. as `?foobar=...` at the end of the URL, as the form is submitted, to the URL that's correspondent with the option selected in the drop-down.

Whether you have a submit button at the end of the form, or not, makes no difference to the behaviour of the form because a form may be submitted even without a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution after doing some searches.

Here is solution in case anyone need it.

```js
        jQuery('#search_page_form').submit(function() {
        // get all the inputs into an array.
        var stext = jQuery('#search_page_form #looking-for').val();
        var cars = jQuery('#search_page_form #cars').val();
        
        var url = '';
        if(cars == 'nns'){
            var url = 'https://careers.huntingtoningalls.com/search/?searchby=location&createNewAlert=false&q='+stext;
        }else if(cars == 'mt'){
            var url = 'https://tsd-careers.hii.com/en-US/search?keywords='+stext;
        }else if(cars == 'is'){
            var url = 'https://careers.huntingtoningalls.com/search/?searchby=location&createNewAlert=false&q='+stext+'&locationsearch=Pascagoula%2C+MS&geolocation=';
        }else if(cars == 'ch'){
            var url = 'https://careers.huntingtoningalls.com/search/?searchby=location&createNewAlert=false&q='+stext+'&locationsearch=Newport+News%2C+VA&geolocation=';
        }
        
        if(url != ''){
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }else{
            alert('Please select Division');
        }
        
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="search_page_form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="looking-for">What are you looking for ?</label>
        <input type="text" id="looking-for" name="looking-for" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter keywords....">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="cars" name="cars" class="form-control nice-select">
          <option selected="" value="">Division</option>
          <option value="nns">NEWPORT NEWS SHIPBUILDING</option>
          <option value="mt">MISSION TECHNOLOGIES</option>
          <option value="is">INGALLS SHIPBUILDING</option>
          <option value="ch">CORPORATE HEADQUARTERS</option>
        </select>
        
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn white-btn search_btn">
      </div>
    </form>
```